# how to create function in Apache Pulsar for docker

Tags: function, apache-pulsar

Step 1:

Copy Jar in container pulsar:

```
docker cp name.jar {ID_CONTAINER}:/pulsar/name.jar
```

Step 2:

Create function in container pulsar :

```
docker exec -it {ID_CONTAINER} bin/pulsar-admin functions create --jar /pulsar/name.jar --className com.mx.conuxi.main.TestFunction --inputs load-valition --output load-errores
```

Regards